# How to delete widget from activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, widget

It is possible to delete widget from main activity ? I am writing small notepad and when some note is deleted, I want to delete widget with this note.

EDIT:

When I do something like this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context); 
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
remoteViews.removeAllViews(R.id.widgetLayout); 
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Widget is not visible (because it do not have any view), but I still can click on it etc.

I want delete widget from home screen in some Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewGroup has several `removeView*(View)` methods. Alternatively you can call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to make the widget disappear from the screen without actually deleting it.

Barry